# Inflection and concavity

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How do I find the intervals when the graph below is concave up and when it's concave down as well as its inflection coordinate points just by looking at the graph?

[image]

I'm able to eyeball it here, but I'm confused with a few parts. I'm pretty sure it concaves up in $(0, 2)\cup(5, \infty)$. I'm not sure if the region around $x=4$ should have its concavity considered because the derivative is not defined at this point.
Then I suspect it concaves down in $(2, 3.5)$. Again, I'm not sure if the point after $x=4$ but just before $x=5$ should be considered an interval where it concaves down, but I doubt it.

Then I think the inflection coordinates are
$(1, 4), (3, 6), (5, 5)$

Comment: $(1, 4)$ is not an inflection point. Inflection is when $f'' = 0$, i.e. the slope that was increasing stops increasing or when it was decreasing and then starts increasing. Inflection point is somewhere between $x = 1$ and $x = 3$ as slope is continuous and is increasing at $x = 1$ ($f' > 0$) and decreasing at $x = 3$($f' < 0$) So by Rolle's theorem there must be $x \in[1, 3]$ such that $f'' = 0$. $(3, 6)$ is also not an inflection point.

Comment: @ab123, that is not true. $f''=0$ doesn't always mean inflection point, for example consider $x\mapsto x^4$, then the double derivative of this function is zero at origin, but that is not a point of inflection.

Comment: @Martund yes, sorry about that. I should have said - If $f''$ changes sign (from positive to negative, or from negative to positive) at a point $x = c$, then there is an inflection point located at $x = c$.

Answer (score 1):

“Concave up” is like the graph of $x^2$ (any arc of it); “concave down” is like the graph of $-x^2$ (any arc of it).

An inflection point is where the curve has a tangent and is concave up on one side and down on the other side (not “globally”, but in some intervals).

At $(1,4)$ there is no change in concavity, and similarly at $(3,6)$. Indeed, these are a point of minimum and a point of maximum respectively.

The change in concavity happens somewhere in between $1$ and $3$ and the visual symmetry leads to guess that the inflection point is at $(2,5)$.

The point $(5,5)$ is indeed an inflection point (at least if we assume that the picture is “accurate”), because the curve is concave down before it and up past it.

What happens at $(4,3)$? This is a point where there is no tangent, so it has to be analyzed separately. The curve is concave up on either side of it, but it's nonetheless a point of minimum.

The intervals where the graph is concave up are: $[0,2]$, $[5,8]$; it is concave down on the intervals $[2,4]$, $[4,5]$.

Note that you should not say $[2,5]$, because the function is not concave down over the whole interval.

Comment: Your answers for concavity were marked correct, only issue was I needed to use parentheses instead of brackets like you did.

However, I'm still not sure what all the inflection points are according to your answer

Comment: @Lex_i They are $(2,5)$ and $(5,5)$, as mentioned in my answer. If your instructor told you that closed intervals are wrong, then *they* are wrong. Another instance of this common error: the function is decreasing over $[0,1]$ and $[3,4}$, increasing over $[1,3]$ and $[4,8]$; using only open intervals would be wrong.